# How does one plot an Abbott Firestone curve

Tags: diagram

I have a Mitutoyo Sj-210, that plots automatically a Firestone curve. I have another device that gives me the SRM values and ect but no curve. I have no idea how the Sj-210 does it despite being useful. How would i plot a Firestone curve manually. What would I have to do on Excel to take the values I have and plot them.

Comment: I never heard of this but looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbott-Firestone_curve it seems you need to do a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel what you should do to generate the curve is the following:

1. take all the measurements for the shaft in one column (name it PROFILE)
2. Sort the data column in ascending/descending order (doesn't really matter)
3. Add another column (name it INDEX) with ascending integer (1,2, 3,4 etc)
4. then add another column (name it CDF) and divide the value in the same row on the INDEX column with the maximum value in the INDEX COLUMN. (You can multiply that by 100% but that is up to you).

Then the Abbot firestone curve can be created by creating a scatter plot diagram with CDF on the X axis and PROFILE on the y-axis.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much